# jqtouch website not working properly in android

Tags: android, scroll, jqtouch

I developed a mobile website using jqtouch. It works fine in iPhone but doesnt work in android.

First the page loads properly in android but when we scroll then it doesnt display anything on the screen. But I am able to click on links and it navigates properly. So am assuming that there is text on the screen but its not getting displayed.

I did look at issues posted in google code where they said that its the problem with transparent gif and suggested to use base64 value. I tried that, even then its not working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an effective way to debug jqt on Android browser. Here are a couple of other ways you should test the page, if you have not done so:

1. Test on Google Chrome.
2. Test on Android Emulator with `adb logcat`. Here is a post describing how you can debug pages in an Android browser: [How can I debug javascript on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried Chrome its working fine. And I will try the adb logcat. But do you know if there is any way to debug the html in android itself. I mean do we have something like firebug?? Or am I expecting too much!!

Comment: I don't you can find firebug-like tools for mobile browsers yet, at least not for mobile Safari and Android browser. I wonder if someone has written an app to do it yet...

Comment: If you are looking for something akin to firebug but to debug html/css/js running on Android or another mobile device, try Weinre: http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem and fixed it  http://html5help.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/fix-jumpy-and-blinky-page-transitions-in-jqtouch/

Answer (score 0):

Just another note on this. The jQTouch download from their website is quite behind. It's a great deal better to get jQTouch from GitHub: https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch

(or if you want something that also allows for fixed headers and/or footers and scrolling areas in between, try the DataZombies fork: https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch).