# jQuery Mobile Loading Image Stuck

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have a simple app that links between pages (divs). On my Samsung Galaxy S running 2.2 it works fine on other Samsung Galaxy S running 2.2  the users get a solid loading image when clicking on one of the links List or Map   and cannot proceed

Any ideas why this may be happening it works fine on emulators etc..

Thanks,
J

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            My App</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="#list_co">List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#map_co">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!--HOME-->
<!--CO-->
<div data-role="page" id="list_co">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            List Counties</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
         <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="co_lst">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="map_co">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            Map Counties</h1>
    </div>
     <div data-role="content">
         <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="co_map">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of jQM are you using? a4.1?

Comment: yep..its weird it works fine on emulator, my phone, browser but not client's phone :( Anyideas on how I can go about debugging on their device...wish their was firebug for android!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android