# JavaScript in Blogger does not work in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, blogger

My page in blogger website works fine except in the mobile browsers.

**The page is [here](https://stylishtextgenerator.online4u.live/).**

Basically, It's a text generator script that is perfectly fine and working but only on desktops not on mobile browsers but when I shift the mode from mobile to desktop browser in the android phone using chrome app it loads the script but in the mobile mode, it's not working at all.

I was wondering if there is any way to fix this.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit more on what does not work? I know it's the JS. But, which part (at least, in term of the site functionality) that does not work?

Comment: My blog's script is loading on desktop browser but not on the mobile browser.

Comment: @HamzaZulfiqar I recommend to connect a smartphone and get javascript console's log - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753708/how-to-view-javascript-console-on-android-and-ios

Comment: The site you linked to in your question wouldn't load for me on my desktop browser.