# How to debug angularjs on android?

Tags: android, angularjs, mobile

I am making an angularjs single page app. It works ok on desktop firefox and chrome. But testing it in androids(2.3.3) browser it seems as angular just doesnt work eg. I can see "{{currentUser.name}}". jsconsole.com does not show any errors just one line "undefined" and angulars service with websocket works and logs periodicaly. I assume there are some logs missing how can I get them? For now the only way to debug I can think of is dividing application into pices and see what doasnt work but it seems so crude.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome allows you to use remote debugging on an android device when you have it connected via usb. See the following page for details on how to do this.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Ok I am going to try this

Comment: Ok so turns out my angular app works just fine on mobile chrome. So I am back to trying to debug androids native browser

Comment: I must admit I didnt look for an answer hard enough. I have found a helpful answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android