# How to open developer tools in Chrome on Android phone

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to open developer tools console in Chrome on Android phones? Without USB debugging. Just some browser which runs chrome Dev tools on Android or an external library or app which can help to achieve that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to open developer tools console in Chrome on Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256331/is-it-possible-to-open-developer-tools-console-in-chrome-on-android-phone)

Comment: Perhaps try [Remote debug Android devices - Chrome for Developers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)

Comment: Also, slightly less related, but I've used 
[Kiwi Browser - Fast & Quiet – Apps on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser&pli=1) successfully to access Developer Tools and Tampermonkey on mobile. ;-)

Answer (score -6):

The Google Store has a code editor called i code go that has a built-in browser with developer tools