# Downloading Image not Working in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, html, download

Here is my script for Downloading an image working perfectly on Computer, But It's not working in Mobile Browsers,Nothing takes place when clicking the Button

Function

```
<script>
function forceDownload(url, fileName){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
        var tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = imageUrl;
        tag.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
        tag.click();
        document.body.removeChild(tag);
    }
    xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

The HTML Script

```
<button onclick=forceDownload("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png","Test") type="button">Download</button></a>
```

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: @MarkoColia But how do we access console in Mobile Browsers ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256331/is-it-possible-to-open-developer-tools-console-in-chrome-on-android-phone & https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/14/debugging-javascript-on-android-and-ios/#:~:text=For%20iOS%20you%20can%20enable,that%20bar%20shows%20the%20console.

Comment: Does this help? `https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp`

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi Nope

Comment: same error here, any answer?