# How can I show the vscode's debug console logs on android device

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to show vscode's debug logs in an android device
is it possible, if it so how can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67905825/17716837 you can open the website on android, click and touch the website on android,  while seeing the `console.log()`s on your desktop by using USB (works on chrome)

Comment: or use this answer that don't need a desktop at all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256331/is-it-possible-to-open-developer-tools-console-in-chrome-on-android-phone but still suggest the first approach (usb debugger chrome android)

Comment: thanks but this work for web developement, I don't interact with web, I want to know how to pass the logs to some tool or api