# How to access developer tools on android chrome on Honeywell EDA 70?

Tags: javascript, android, html, web, honeywell

On Chrome on Android phone, we can use remote debugging ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256331/is-it-possible-to-open-developer-tools-console-in-chrome-on-android-phone)).

But this needs USB portal and [Honeywell EDA 70](https://prod-edam.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell-edam/sps/ppr/en-us/public/products/mobile-computers/tablets/eda70/documents/sps-ppr-scanpal-eda70-tablet-handheld-computer-data-sheet-en.pdf) has no USB port. How to open developers tools here?

Basically it is scanning a QR code and our webpage reads it using `onScan: function(scannedData)` but the field are not being properly populated and we cannot simulate the QR code scan on a computer. So we need to debug this and we can't access developer tools on Honeywell device.

Comment: You could try using a browser with dev tools built in, kiwi browser for android seems to have this -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1   Alternative get a dock for it, looks like some come with the USB bit.

Comment: From curiosity did a research and there is actually Usb connection. If look up in the [accessories guide](https://prod-edam.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell-edam/sps/ppr/es-mx/public/products/mobile-computers/tablets/eda70/documents/sps-ppr-scanpal-eda70-tablet-handheld-computer-accessory-guide-en.pdf) there is charging cradle which supports data transfer with usb which should work for dev tools.

Comment: @fatm thanks for the input, we will try to do this