# Is there a way to type and evaluate Javascript on Android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, console

Is it possible to type and evaluate Javascript solely on an Android browser (any browser with any plugin/configuration, doesn't matter) w/o involving a desktop (Remote or USB debugging)?

I need that to obtain the value of a dynamic login token of a website on an Android device. So I need to be able to evaluate and output:

```
 console.log(sb233.sb)
 alert.log(sb233.sb)
```

In which case "sb233" is a variable accessible on the console of a desktop browser.

Asking coz I don't really want to go as far as to write a plugin for this purpose only...

Comment: You can add a `JavascriptInterface` and return virtually any value from your DOM. You can also inject any javascript through `loadUrl()`

Comment: i don't think he's talking about android development, i think he's asking about mobile-browers in general, to which i would say, typing javascript into a phone is asinine. just change the user agent in your desktop browser to get the mobile version of whatever it is youre trying to messwith.

Comment: however, it would be relatively easy to build a mobile browesr that takes junk from a text box and executes it in a webview over another website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen from here:

[How can I debug javascript on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android)

> Pierre-Antoine LaFayette wrote:
>
> You can also navigate to about:debug in the URL bar to activate the
>   debug menu and the JavaScript error console with recent Android
>   devices. You should see SHOW JAVASCRIPT CONSOLE at the top of the
>   Browser.
>
> Currently in Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich), the logcat outputs to
>   the browser channel. So you can filter using adb logcat browser:* *:S.