# Android studio - Debug Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, android-studio

I have to debug an Android app into Android Studio; the app contains scripts written in Javascript. Is there a way to add breakpoints to line of codes written in Javascript?

Comment: Yes it is possible to Debug Javescript in android, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug javascript on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open chrome and go to  DevTools ( Inspect Element),
- click the Main Menu then select More tools > Remote devices.
- open the Settings tab.
- Make sure that the Discover USB devices checkbox is enabled.
- Connect your Android device directly to your development machine
  using a USB cable. The first time you do this, you usually see that
  DevTools has detected an unknown device. If you see a green dot and
  the text Connected below the model name of your Android device, then
  DevTools has successfully established the connection to your device
- In the Remote Devices tab, click the tab that matches your Android
  device model name and Click "Inspect"

check this link  for debugging JavaScript on Android in details

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 2):

Or easier way - in Chrome (or any Chromium-based browser as Edge) type url: chrome://inspect#devices.